# Regression of irregular time series

Tags: regression, time-series, dataset, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I am beginning to look at high frequency data sets. I have only ever dealt with regularly spaced data up until now so wondering what best practice is.

If I have two time series X and Y with Y being the dependent variable, if both time series are irregular is the only way to regress Y against X to perform some form of interpolation on both series?

Or is there a way to consider the time between data points as equal in duration and then perform a regression with X lagged against Y. I assume would have to consider that if you get a data point for  X at time stamp 0 mics then the next data point in Y must occur after  xx mics since it takes time for any response to occur in Y in relation to X.

Is there a good way to determine that duration of response time? or is this just an assumption?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33796/is-there-any-gold-standard-for-modeling-irregularly-spaced-time-series/392355#392355