# statsmodels seasonal_decompose(): What is the right "period of the series" in the context of a list column (constant vs. varying number of items)

Tags: time-series, seasonality, trend, statsmodels, decomposition

Assume having a *list column* so that your time series is *nested*, see [Convert pandas df with data in a “list column” into a time series in long format. Use three columns: [list of data] + [timestamp] + [duration]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246938/convert-pandas-df-with-data-in-a-list-column-into-a-time-series-in-long-format) for details. The question here is not about how to *unnest* a *list column* though. Assume that you already have a long format structure with all available *list elements unnested* into a *normal column*, here for example taking 2 lists with 4 list elements, making 8 rows in the end.

Part1: Assume that every *list* of the original *list column* has the same number of list elements (here, the first list with 4 items around 08:53, and the second with 4 items around 08:55).

```
                     value
datetimeindex
2016-05-04 08:53:20  1
2016-05-04 08:53:21  2
2016-05-04 08:53:22  1
2016-05-04 08:53:23  9
2016-05-04 08:55:00  2
2016-05-04 08:55:01  2
2016-05-04 08:55:02  3
2016-05-04 08:55:03  0
```

Now approaching the actual question. From [statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose¶](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html) we read:

*Definition of period*

> "period, int, optional"
>
> Period of the series. Must be used if x is not a pandas object or if
> the index of x does not have a frequency. Overrides default
> periodicity of x if x is a pandas object with a timeseries index.

What is meant here with "Period of the series"? Is it:

1. the number of lists, here 2.
2. the standard size of a list. This would be 4 in the example.
3. something else than 1./2.

Please also explain what would be different if you had a "Part2 setting", if there is any difference:

Part2: Assume that every *list* of the original *list column* has a varying number of list elements (here, the first list with 4 items around 08:53, and the second with just 3 items around 08:55).

```
                     value
datetimeindex
2016-05-04 08:53:20  1
2016-05-04 08:53:21  2
2016-05-04 08:53:22  1
2016-05-04 08:53:23  9
2016-05-04 08:55:00  2
2016-05-04 08:55:01  2
2016-05-04 08:55:02  3
```

***The examples shall make the question clear, no programming (especially not with the examples) needed for an accepted answer.***

*Context:*

This question arose from [decompose() for time series: ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017052/decompose-for-time-series-valueerror-you-must-specify-a-period-or-x-must-be/63252466).

Comment: Bounties become more noticeable towards the end of the period, as they move towards the top of the [list](https://stats.stackexchange.com/?tab=bounties). That said, it is notable that this Q has only 21 views, a number of which are me checking on it. You may want to ask a question on [meta.stats.SE] to see if there's a way to raise the profile of this Q &/or make it more answerable. (Again, this doesn't seem to be a programming Q, & there are so many Qs on [SO] that they usually get less attention than here.)

Comment: (1) The time-series data's having previously been stored in a nested list isn't obviously relevant. Some explanation is required of what that has to do with the choice of period for decomposition. (2) *Period* is the no. observations in a seasonal cycle - e.g. if you've daily observations & weekly seasonality, the period is 7. But your observations are at irregular intervals, & how to perform seasonal decomposition on irregular time series is perhaps the crux of your question (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/244042/17230 & https://stackoverflow.com/q/12623027/1864816).

Comment: @Scortchi would you mind making an answer from your comment? It says that the period parameter does not play a role if the data does not have any cycles. Since there is no answer up to now, you are likely right with all. And it should not be just a comment then. Not sure how to reach you since this Q was migrated.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica Please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Without cycles

The "period" parameter does not play a role if the data does not have any cycles. This short example cannot have a seasonality in it. Thus, the answer to the question is that there is no answer.

##### With cycles, and with observations at regular intervals

The "period" parameter is the number of observations in a seasonal cycle. For example, if you have daily observations and weekly seasonality, the period is 7.

##### With cycles, and with observations at irregular intervals

Not asked in the example of this question, but *if* the data had a seasonality and by the same time irregular intervals, there are questions dealing with this:

- Trend in irregular time series data
- How to analyse irregular time-series in R

Thanks go to the remarks of user [Scortchi](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/17230/scortchi-reinstate-monica).