# GAM model parameter estimation problems

Tags: r, mgcv, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have been trying to develop a GAM to predict future subsidence from previous subsidence data. I am new to GAM and have based my code on [this].[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244042/trend-in-irregular-time-series-data) The data looks like this:

```
    Longitude Latitude       Time Subsidence YEAR month
81   76.29542 10.05154 2015-10-12 0.02640557 2015    10
82   76.29615 10.05154 2015-10-12 0.02955222 2015    10
83   76.29688 10.05154 2015-10-12 0.02672001 2015    10
84   76.29761 10.05154 2015-10-12 0.02426790 2015    10
221  76.29396 10.05081 2015-10-12 0.02521223 2015    10
222  76.29469 10.05081 2015-10-12 0.02637761 2015    10
```

These have been extracted from rasters if that is relevant. Also, the time series is not regular. Measurements have been taken at unequal periods.

I used the following code:

```
library(mgcv)
knots <- list(month = c(0.5, 12.5))
M <- list(c(1, 0.5), NA)
m_test2 <- bam(Subsidence ~ 
s(month, k = 9, bs = "cc") + 
YEAR + 
s(Longitude, Latitude, k = 500, bs = "ds", m = c(1, 1)) + 
ti(month, YEAR, bs = c("cc", "tp"), k = c(6, 5)) + 
ti(Longitude,  Latitude, month, d = c(2, 1), bs = c("ds", "cc"),    m = M, k = c(125, 6)) + 
ti(Longitude, Latitude, YEAR, d = c(2,  1), bs = c("ds", "tp"), m = M, k = c(125, 5)), data = train.data, method = 'fREML',nthreads = 4, discrete = TRUE)
```

The results were significant:

```
Parametric coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -44.800334   1.817401  -24.65   <2e-16 ***
YEAR          0.022156   0.000899   24.64   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                 edf Ref.df         F p-value    
s(month)                       6.368      7   8051.95  <2e-16 ***
s(Longitude,Latitude)        483.440    499    272.70  <2e-16 ***
ti(YEAR,month)                10.632     11 142633.62  <2e-16 ***
ti(month,Longitude,Latitude) 289.637    496     25.11  <2e-16 ***
ti(YEAR,Longitude,Latitude)  418.624    496    170.17  <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.949   Deviance explained = 94.9%
fREML = -7.734e+05  Scale est. = 0.00015087  n = 260248
```

However the `gam.check()` plots showed this:
[image] [image]
[image] [image]

The predictions are also way off. I have changed the k values multiple times and removed outliers, but this has remained the same. This is my first time doing a GAM and I don't know how to proceed.