# Time series or panel data models that can deal with irregular time intervals and multiple observations in some but not all time periods

Tags: r, time-series, multiple-regression, panel-data

I want to run a time series regression over data is not spaced out in regular time intervals and where in some time periods there are multiple observations. Such in the picture below.

[image]

Is this possible and are there any models that are appropriate for this with out having to alter the data?

Comment: With the irregular spaces I would not consider it *changing the data* to interpolate the missing dates with zeroes. Any time series method is going to require that. Regression will not necessarily require evenly spaced data. You could use the data as-is with a linear regression. What are you measuring, and what's your goal (are you trying to predict the future or understand the relationship b/w variables explaining the past)? Answer these questions and we can give suggestions.

Comment: The score is a sentiment analysis score which analyses news headlines. I want to see if the sentiment of headlines have a predictive impact on stock prices. I would like to be able to control for a range of other variables too.

Comment: And what does one observation mean? why are there more one score sometimes, and zero other times?

Comment: I could average the sentiment scores of multiple news articles and perhaps create a variable which counts how many articles there were that day. This is why ideally I would prefer not to average over stories because it will lose a lot of the variation in the stories.

Comment: To clarify I think that I would want a model something like this 

$ P _ { t } = \alpha + P _ { t -1 } + \beta X _ { t - 1 } + \varepsilon _ { t } $ where $ P _ { t } $ is the share price and  $ \beta X _ { t - 1 }$ is a range of controls including the news sentiment scores

Comment: you could build that model with the data as-is. That's not a time-series model so that data does not need to be equally spaced. You are choosing to ignore the days that have no analysis score. It is a separate issue as to whether or not you should ignore them, it would depend at least on why you don't have a score (there are truly no articles that meet some criteria, or it's missing data).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any gold standard for modeling irregularly spaced time series?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33796/is-there-any-gold-standard-for-modeling-irregularly-spaced-time-series)